# How to get Lubuntu to forget wifi connection when new user logs in

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, login, logout, wifi-direct

My wifi works fine on my Lubuntu system, but is there a way to make it forget the wifi login credentials after a user logs out? I need other users to sign in with their own (web authorization page-) credentials if they login.

Comment: this is major security flaw

Answer (score 1):

Lubuntu uses NetworkManager. [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/236672/38150) explaines how to delete a know network.

```
sudo rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/NETWORK_NAME
```

If I understand correctly from [this](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/212) source, run-level 5 is for graphical logins:

> Run levels 2 through 5 are full multi-user mode and are the same in a
>   default UserLinux (Debian) system. It is a common practise in other
>   Linux distributions to use run level 3 for a text console login and
>   run level 5 for a graphical login.

You wrap the above command in a executable script and link it to `/etc/rc5.d/your_script`.
A little more information can be found in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/127455/140449)

Comment: the thing is when i connect to wifi and then open firefox i will go to web authentication page were i need to login with my user account, if i then log out from my account and login with new user account it will have save my web authentication login and the next person can use my credentials and have access to all my network share's and files

Comment: Doesn't the browser give you the option of saving your credentials? If so, simply deny it.

Comment: its nothing to do with browser its Lubuntu, I will giv you exsample..

Comment: I log on to Lubuntu with test 1 account conect to internet via wife when i first open browser tsakes me to web authetication page on our coprate network i login with AD account and d some work, then i log out from Lubuntu. 


Next I log in with testuser 2 and open web browser I am all ready conected to web via test user 1's credentials this is Lubuntu that is remembering the credentials

Comment: Thats weird. You are not starting Firefox as root (both times)?

Comment: no 2nd user is just a  standard user

Comment: if you Think you take laptop to hotel and login to there wifi then someone eles logins in to my laptop with new user account they can also surf the net useing the same login details i put in when i was logged in, so if you Think in a Corporate a guest user login to laptop with guest account but is connected to the network with the last administrators log who was on the laptop 10 mins Before this is a huge security fail

Comment: yes this will just not work and we wonder why Corporates stick with Microsoft when you can't even do somehting as simple as this it like i login to my internet bank then log out and new user logs on to laptop or pc opens internet goes to same bank page and are all ready logged in with my bank details its  huge masive security fail

Comment: What happens when you tried this with a different browser?

Comment: as for useing this sudo rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/NETWORK_NAME

the user would need to be admin user and this would need to be done everytime after a person had logged in to the pc or laptop just going to happen

Comment: its nothing to do with the browser its down to Lubuntu/Ubuntu keeping the login

Comment: ok I have tested with 7 other browsers now just for you still the same thing

Comment: I can't explain this behaviour at the moment. Please fill in a [bug report](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/ReportingBugs).

Answer (score 0):

**Addressing the distraction first**

In the dialog between 'mercmanager2' and 'OrangeTux' there seems to be some miscommunication.  I'm not sure I understand the confusion clearly, but it looks to me like 'mercmanager2' is confusing the wifi access point login with a website login.

Network Manager does indeed remember access point credentials.  For a single user system, this is a huge convenience.  If you want to delete an access point, right click on the network manager, select 'edit connections', then select the wifi tab, select the access point, and click delete.

If you want this to happen automatically, "OrangeTux's" advice is correct, but will only take place on power down, depending on how you attach it to the rc.5 daemon, which by the way is not for the faint of heart.

Browser configurations, in contrast, are kept in the user login home directory and are absolutely isolated.  If I log into a bank, then log out and another family member logs into their SEPARATE user account, they will absolutely be automatically connected to the wifi access point.  They will NOT however have access to my bank without credentials, even if I choose, for my convenience, to save my bank login credentials in my browser settings (which is a bad idea - a big risk for a small convenience).

**Returning to the original question**

Again, there is a little lack of clarity.  There are different levels of login:

1. to the Lubuntu system
2. to the (presumably) secured wifi access point
3. to the server hosting the router (firewall or intranet server)
   which may or may not exist in "mercmanager2's" situation
4. and finally to a web server on the internet somewhere

The latter is ALWAYS handled in the browser, not the OS, whether you use Lubuntu or Microsoft or MacOS.

The way the question is worded, I'll suppose there is a firewall server.  It appears "mercmanager2" wishes to authenticate each internet user on a shared machine individually to the firewall.  An example would be a public library, where different users log in through the same wifi access point, but have to provide personal credentials (a library card number) to access the internet.

If the logins are being passed through, this is something you can NOT correct on your local machine, be it Linux, Windows, or Mac.  This is something being handled at the firewall.  At my library, my personal machine gets a lease, associated with my machine's MAC address (a number identifying my wifi hardware).  When I change users on my machine, the lease on the server is still valid, so I am passed through.

In contrast, the library's public machines enforce authentication. The lease is canceled when a user logs out and a new lease is issued when a new user logs on.  This is done on the firewall, not the public machine.  This is the same, whether the firewall uses MacOS, Windows, or Linux.

If that is not the issue, then I can't make sense of the original question.

Comment: This is not correct, on a windows system when i create a new user then log in, i will need to put in wifi login details, 

Also with the Lubuntu even after useing "OrangeTux's" advice and then Power Down when start up and log on with other user it is all ready conected to the wifi and by passed the login page. Also on Windows when a User logs out if they are useing our Public internet they would need to put in username and password next time they logged in.